# better way for creating html forms

Tags: html, forms, webforms

i am here to find out which way is better for creating better html forms:

1.) `<form><ul><li><lable>` like:

```
<form ...>
     <fieldset>
          <ul>
               <li>
                    <label for="...">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" value="..." />
               </li>
               <li>
                    <label for="...">Email</label>
                    <input name="Email" value="..." />
               </li>
               <li>
                    <label for="...">Address</label>
                    <input name="address" value="..." />
               </li>
               <li>
                    <label for="...">&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="submit" value="..." />
               </li>
          </ul>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

2.) `<form><dl>` like:

```
<form ...>
     <fieldset>
           <dl>
                <label for="...">Name</label>
                <input name="name" value="..." />
           </dl>
           <dl>
                <label for="...">Email</label>
                <input name="Email" value="..." />
           </dl>
           <dl>
                <label for="...">Address</label>
                <input name="address" value="..." />
           </dl>
           <dl>
                <label for="...">&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" value="..." />
           </dl>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [W3 guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#forms)

They use

```
   <FORM action="submit" method="post">
         <LABEL for="user" accesskey="U">name</LABEL>
         <INPUT type="text" id="user">
   </FORM>
```

Further on down this link they show how to group form controls.